# Theano ImportError: cannot import name opt

Tags: python-2.7, theano, importerror

I'm trying to set-up for the fast.ai course (python 2.7) on windows 8 (cpu only on my computer and eventually aws) and am running into a lot of problems. When a script in the 1st jupiter note book runs it gives me "ImportError: cannot import name opt" even though it is literally in the same folder.

```
    C:\Users\student\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\__init__.py in <module>()
     13     TensorConstantSignature, TensorConstant)
     14 
---> 15 from theano.tensor import opt
     16 from theano.tensor import opt_uncanonicalize
     17 from theano.tensor import blas
```

I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ananaconda 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Not sure if the below solution will solve the problem on Windows 8, still you can give it a try.

For some of the guys the system reboot does solved the problem.
For me the following steps solved the issue.

Uninstall theano. Then install theano requirement packages.

```
$ conda install mkl nose sphinx pydot-ng
```

Then

```
$ conda install theano
```

Please refer http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/install_ubuntu.html for more details about theano installation.

Comment: I have the package installed and updated as well as all other requirements. still the same massage.